# Code does compile but no output

Tags: c++

I have made this code that should build two vectors, one with the integers up to 100 and the other with the squares of these integers, and would like to write two columns so that the values line up in two columns. The program compiles ok, but the output is empty, i.e., nothinkg appears but only the message "Process returned 0 (0x0)". What exactly am I missing here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    vector<int> numbers;
    typedef vector<int>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size = numbers.size();

    for (vec_sz i = 0; i != numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        numbers.push_back(i);
    }

    vector<int> squares;

    for (vec_sz i = 0; i!= squares.size(); i++)
    {
        squares.push_back(i^2);
    }
    for (vec_sz i = 0; i != numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << setw(3)
        << numbers[i]
        << setw(6)
        << squares[i]
        << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you try to debug, you'll find that......all the for loops don't execute at all.

Comment: `numbers` is empty when you enter your first loop, so it is entirely skipped, and thus everything else as well (and that's a good thing, because even a single element will introduce an infinite growth loop; `i` would never catch up to `numbers.size()` because you increase that size with each iteration).

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger. You'll notice it's much faster and easier than to write a question here and wait for an answer, especially for basic problems.

Comment: @WhozCraig why is numbers empty? What is wrong in the loop?

Comment: @RandomGuy It's is empty because you haven't filled it yet.

Comment: As I said, it's empty from the start, and nothing is ever added because `i < number.size()` is false (both are zero from the start), and therefore everything else is skipped. And seriously, think *hard* about that condition if you think pushing an element in before that loop is a solution; it is *not*. That would guarantee an infinite consumption loop.

Comment: The description says you need a vector with 100 elements. However, the constant 100 doesn't appear anywhere in the program; How is the program to know that the number of elements needs to be 100?

Comment: @MrLister yes, I understand now. I made a silly error. Thanks

Comment: @RandomGuy Please note that you made the same error three times in a row.

Comment: Default constructed vectors have zero size, so the body of the two loops pushing elements into `numbers` and `squares` will never be executed.  That means `numbers.size()` will still be zero for the third loop, so the body of that loop (which is the only place in your code that will produce output) will never be executed either.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this line at the beginning of your main function,

```
vec_sz size = numbers.size();
```

you want to obtain the size of the vector. However, `numbers` is empty, it does not contain any data. Hence size will be 0. Here `numbers.size()` is going to return 0.

Hence `for (vec_sz i = 0; i != numbers.size(); ++i)` will not execute even once.

Let's say that you want to fill `numbers`, then you should know how many values do you want to fill in `numbers`. Once you know this value, store it in a variable let's say `count`.

Sample:

```
const int count = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    numbers.push_back(i);
}

// now numbers.size() will return 10;
```

Same goes for your `squares` vector.

Comment: _"Once you know this value, store it in a variable"_ Yes but make it `const`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, true. The user may also be asked to input the value for `count`.